# Get /extract the real data from Cacti database

Tags: php, rrdtool, rrd, cacti

**I use [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)** to monitor my network devices and it works.
But I have some trouble when I try to get data without graph (stored to text).

So I tried to make my own SNMP monitoring app with a traffic formula:
 `(Data(now)-Data(now-1)*8/time interval)`.

Somehow, I have different values with cacti and idk.
So I tried to find out how Cacti is measuring data with SNMP but I failed.

Is it possible to extract data from cacti graphs like current and average to string??
Or maybe to get real data from Cacti code before it is stored to RRD database??

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is to use the inbuilt functionality available with RRDTool.

There's a couple of options rrdxport (https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdxport.en.html) or rrddump (https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html).

The links provided give comprehensive examples of the syntax and functionality.